# python unitest - How to convert a "with" clause to setUp/tearDown

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a class full of tests that begin with a `with` clause to set up a complicated set of environments and resources.  Each of the with lines is long and repetitive.

I'd like to convert these to a single implementation as `setUp()` and `teardDown()`

Essentially I want something like:

```
    def setUp(self):
        self.unit = # some long initialisation

    def tearDown(self):
        self.unit.__exit__()
```

For example: imagine this is simplified to use `open()`

```py
class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        with open('filename', 'r') as f:
            # do testing with f
...
    def test_100(self):
        with open('filename', 'r') as f:
            # do testing with f
```

I'd convert it to:

```py
  class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.f = open("filename', 'r')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.f.close()

    def test_1(self):
        # do testing with self.f
...
    def test_100(self):
        # do testing with self.f
```

Now this works because file has a common, easily reproduced `__exit__` equivalent  namely `close()`.

In our case the `__exit__` handler is fairly complex, type dependent, and stateful - and (except for test-purposes) we don't want to expose a `close()` like API (because that adds stateful complexity) and would allow clients not to use the `with` clause as designed.

Is there some way to invoke `__exit__` appropriately?  Or integrate the `with as` clause around each test case?

Comment: Have you tried just calling `self.cm.__exit__(None, None, None)`? [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__)

Comment: No I haven't - I was expecting there to be something more elegant

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, I would think that calling `self.cm.__exit__(None, None, None)` in the `tearDown` method would work just fine.

```
def tearDown(self):
    self.cm.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

However, I got to thinking about another pattern you could try:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import unittest

class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @contextmanager
    def harness(self):
        with open('file.txt', 'r') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'w') as f2:
            try:
                yield f1, f2
            finally:
                pass

    def test_one(self):
        with self.harness() as (f1, f2):
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks - `__exit__(None,...)` might actually work, but it didn't seem "right" - I was hoping for more elegant solutions.  You've got a good example of avoiding the complicated line.  I will also look into direct decoration of tests.

Answer (score 1):

In the end decorators is probably more elegant that `setUp`, `tearDown` (with lots of arguments skipped)

```
def with_single_unit(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def with_single_unit_(self):
        with SingleUnitStage(lotsa_args_skipped).select(lotsa_args_skipped) as unit:
            self.unit = unit
            fn(self)
    return with_single_unit_

class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @with_single_unit
    def test_a(self):
       # use self.unit

    @with_single_unit
    def test_b(self):
       # use self.unit

    @with_single_unit
    def test_c(self):
       # use self.unit
```